# write recursively different DFs in a xlsx without overwriting using Jupyter

Tags: pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, xlsx, xlsxwriter

I have 100 csv files to analyse, which I open recursively, analyse the data, and then I would like to write the results in a xlsx file.

I want to write all the results in the same xlsx file, without overwriting the results of the previous files, and putting the data one below the other. (I cannot put the results in a DF and then append all of them due to memory issue).

Briefly, the idea is as follow

```
for file in folder:
    open the csv
    analyse the data
    Results into a DF
    Results into Xlsx (starting from the first free row)
```

any suggestion? 
thanks

Comment: read this, it has code block you fix ur issue : https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/27051

Comment: Thanks for the quick hint. I get the following error NameError: name 'col2num' is not defined. is there a package that I need to import?

Comment: do all your analysis and concat everything to single dataframe and write to excel

Comment: @pyd I was doing exactly that, but I have two issues: first one is memory issue, i.e my machine cannot cope with the size of the final DF, which has more than 2 million rows; the code is super slow. Instead, if I append the results into spreadsheets, I expect that the code would be a bit faster, and the DF will have less rows by analysing individual files